# I do not understand what this question requires of me

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

The following question is incomprehensible to me: ''Prove that for the equation $e^{y-1} +\ln y +x^3 =1$ there exists a differnetiable solution $y(x)$ in the neighbourhood of $ x_0=0$ and fulfills $y(0)=1$. Prove that $y'(0)=y''(0)=0$. Sort the extremum point $x=0$ of $y(x)$.''

When do they mean when they say '' there exists a differentiable solution''? Isn't it true that for every equation of continuous and differentiable functions, the solution/s will always be differentiable either way?

Comment: No, it's not true. For instance, take $xy=1$. The solution $y(x)$ is not even defined at $x=0$, let alone differentiable.

Comment: @Moo It is 100%

Comment: @Raskolnikov You should not have allowed Porfiry Petrovich capture you. Good point btw.

Comment: You should take a derivative of the equation with respect to X, and see what happens

Comment: I've done my time in the camps now. I can get him back. :p

Comment: BEGIN QUOTE Isn't it true that for every equation of continuous and differentiable functions, the solution/s will always be differentiable either way? END QUOTE _If_ it is true that every such equation defines a differentiable function, then that is something that would require proof. Why do you phrase the question negatively, saying "Isn't it true?" instead of "Is it true?"

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didnt really understand the point of the question

Comment: I've seen people phrasing mathematical questions negatively before, saying "Isn't it true that X?", and suggest that if X is true, then there's no point in asking whether it is.

Comment: As a counterexample, $y = |x|$ is a solution to $y^2 = x^2$ but it is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-By "solution "$y(x)"$ you must understand that there is in the plane curve of equation $F(x,y)=e^{y-1} +\ln y +x^3-1=0$ an implicit function $y=f(x)=\text{?}$ defined in a certain neighbourhood of $x_0=0$  about which you must proved the requested properties. I feel that you cannot find a closed form for $f(x)$ but it is possible to prove the required questions.

Comment: It is almost sure that what are you demanded to prove it is valid (fitting in each case and, for example  $y(x)\ne 1$ for all $x\ne 0$) neighbourhood of x belonging to the domain of $\ln y$ which is suggested by the graphic of the curve $F(x,y)$.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Thanks you very much for your editing despite I cannot see what you have changed. My English is quite deficient.